# ASP Site, when deployed, does not contain ASP chart control

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, charts, windows-server-2008-r2, web-deployment

I am attempting to deploy a small ASP site onto a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, using IIS 7.

When the site is tested on the development machine, using Visual Studio 2013 Express Web, it works perfectly. The JQuery/Javascript stuff works great, the ASP controls (all charts. 2 pie charts and a bar chart, contained with an update panel) all display great: its a website paradise. But once I deploy it on the web server with IIS 7, the ASP controls vanish. The Javascript/JQuery all run awesomely, but the ASP charts are nowhere to be found.

Note: On the version hosted on the server, I right clicked -> View Source (in IE). I couldn't find a single ASP control in the source. Nada. ****Zerkey Explained this below. Thank you!****

These are the steps I have taken so far:

On the web server:

```
* Installed IIS with ALL addons available 
* Installed .NET 4.0 and made sure the application pool was set to .NET v4.0.
* Navigated to the .NET 4.0 folder and ran "aspnet_regiis -i"
* The site was deployed via Publish -> Deployment Package in Visual Studio. It was 
  set up using "Import Application" on the server. No special options were selected: 
  only default options were used across the board.
* Restarted the whole machine
```

On the web site itself:

```
* Made sure EVERY asp control had <runat="server"> on it. Every...single...one
* Made sure that System.Web.DataVisualization, in references, was set to 
  Local Copy: True.
```

I am a complete loss. :( Can anyone think of something I didn't list here that I could try? Any advice would be amazing :)

Thank you!

EDIT: Correction- The ASP Buttons, the only other ASP controls on the site besides the charts, are displaying just fine. It's the CHARTS that are not displaying. Updated question title accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, chose the wrong tag. Should have chosen ASP.NET, and accidentally chose ASP-Classic

Comment: ASP.NET controls are rendered as HTML serverside, so if you are viewing the source through Internet Explorer (or any browser) you should never see the controls.

Comment: Aha, that explains the it missing in the source! I'm still learning ASP stuff, this is my own little test page, so I always appreciate information like that :)

Comment: Cool how you can install IIS and the framework on a server (way over my head) and yet I can still help you will the small stuff. <3 Stack OverFlow. Are the controls being rendered properly, do you see them visually?

Comment: Negative- that's the issue I'm having: they don't render at all. All the javascript and jquery and basic html stuff renders fine, but the part where the ASP charts should show up... there are no charts. Not even a hint that any ASP control exists on the page.

And yea, Stack Overflow is great. =D

Comment: Actually, I take that back! The ASP button controls are rendering just fine! It's only the charts that are not rendering!

Comment: Huh. Charts are another area I haven't worked with, although a quick google search of "asp charts iis7" reveals a common problem. Try [this link](http://asifhuddani.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/chart-control-asp-net-4-0-and-iis-7-problem/).